# Connection to CloudSQL from Cloud Function ends in 403 Forbbiden, IAM role not assigned or CloudSQL API not enabled

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, database-connection

first of all I want to apologize in advance, I was going to write this text with the English I have learned but then I realized that it was a better idea to translate it in DeepL.

I am having a problem connecting to the database hosted in CloudSQL only from a Cloud Function, which is in the same project and in the same region as the CloudSQL instance, the message is as follows:

```
'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 403, message="Forbidden: Authenticated IAM principal does not seeem authorized to make API request. Verify 'Cloud SQL Admin API' is enabled within your GCP project and 'Cloud SQL Client' role has been granted to IAM principal.", url=URL('https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/demobleett/instances/demobleett-test/connectSettings')"
```

The service account linked to the Cloud Function has the editor role, plus I tried adding the role mentioned in the error message to it anyway, it had no effect.
The strange thing is that I have the same functionality implemented in the same way in another project and it works perfectly. When migrating the same functionality to two other projects, both fail with the same message. I tried replicating the CloudSQL instance of the project that is working and adjusting the regions well, it didn't work either. I am not an expert in the cloud, I guessed that maybe it is not so important the difference in regions, since in the project that does work one is in Sao Paulo and the other in Warsaw.

The CF source is literally a zip of the code that works in the other project, the only difference are the environment variables, they correspond to the API they consume and the connection to the DB.

Needless to say that the instance id, user, password and database name are fine. We've been stuck in my work for days without finding a real solution. I consult here since I got ChatGPT dizzy haha.

Since the connection works in the other project, I didn't think to provide the package and driver used for the connection. Basically I followed a notebook from Google Documentation, we used SQLAlchemy and pg8000.

Thanks to all in advance, greetings.

Comment: are you sure about your connection string and the Cloud SQL project?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I literally copy and paste the db information from CF env variables to my local code, the problem is in the CF environment clearly.

Comment: Your local environment does not use the same credential!

Comment: Can you try to grant this role to your Cloud Functions service account "Cloud SQL Instance User"?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I know that. But what I don't understand here is that the service account of the CF of the project in which this workflow is working has the same role as the service account of the CF of the project that is not working. Both have the editor role, which includes the permissions granted by the SQL instance user: cloudsql.instances.get
cloudsql.instances.login

Comment: Hmm, strange indeed. Maybe a Googel Cloud bug. Open a ticket to the support.